# Удаление данных с клиента и сервера с использованием React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Изучаю React, и вот на просторах интернета наткнулся на небольшой туториал по которому у меня возник вопрос

Есть такой вот код:

```html
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios'

class TableRow extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.delete = this.delete.bind(this);
    }

    delete() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4200/serverport/delete/' + this.props.obj._id)
            .then(console.log('Deleted'))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.obj._id}</td>
                <td>{this.props.obj.name}</td>
                <td>{this.props.obj.port}</td>
                <td>
                    <Link to={"/edit/" + this.props.obj._id} className="btn btn-primary">Edit</Link>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button onClick={this.delete} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}

export default TableRow;
```

```html
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import TableRow from './TableRow'

export default class IndexComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            serverports: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4200/serverport')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({serverports: response.data})
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    tabRow() {
        return this.state.serverports.map((objects, i) => {
            return <TableRow
                obj={objects}
                key={i}/>
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{marginTop: 50}}>
                <div className={"container"}>
                    <table className={"table table-striped"}>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>Port</td>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {this.tabRow()}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

По кнопке "Delete" данные удаляются, но на стороне сервера, то есть только после перезагрузки страницы я вижу, что именно удалил. А как сделать так, чтобы удалить запись и на клиенте, без перезагрузки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как мне кажется у вас 2 варианта:

1) После успешного удаления заново перезапросить список записей с сервера.

2) Поместить ваш список в `state` родительской компоненты и делать `map` именно по списку из `state`, а после успешного удаления удалять эту запись из `state`.

Ответил достаточно общими словами, но это только из-за того что не вижу вашу родительскую компоненту:)

UPD: я бы сделал так:

1) В родителе сделал бы функцию удаления записи:

```
removeRecord = (item) => {
    this.setState({
         serverports: this.state.serverports.filter(e=> e._id !== item._id)
    })
}
```

2) Прокинул бы эту функцию в `child` компоненту:

```
tabRow() {
        return this.state.serverports.map((objects, i) => {
            return <TableRow
                obj={objects}
                key={i}
                removeRecord={this.removeRecord}
             />
        });
    };
```

3) В `child` компоненте, в том месте где ваше `console.log('Deleted')` вызвал бы функцию:

```
delete() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4200/serverport/delete/' + this.props.obj._id)
            .then(() => {
                   console.log('Deleted')
                   this.props.removeRecord(this.props.obj)
             })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

Comment: Вопрос дополнил родительским компонентом, буду благодарен, если сможете указать или показать, что именно следует сделать в данном случае :)

Comment: @DmitriyV. обновил ответ:)

Comment: Спасибо вам, все заработало!

Comment: @DmitriyV. Отлично:)